# SceneKit 3D Marker Augmented Reality iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, augmented-reality, scenekit

Last couple of weeks I've been working on developing a simple proof-of-concept application in which a 3D model is projected over a specific Augmented Reality marker (in my case I am using Aruco markers) in IOS (with Swift and Objective-C)

I calibrated an Ipad Camera with a specific fixed lens position and used that to estimate the pose of the AR marker (which from my debug analysis seem pretty accurate). The problem seems (surprise, surprise) when I try to use SceneKit scene to project a model over the marker.

I am aware that the axis in opencv and SceneKit are different (Y and Z) and already done this correction as well as the row order/column order difference between the two libraries.

After constructing the projection matrix, I apply that same transform to the 3D model and from my debug analysis the object seems to be translated to the desired position and with the desired rotation. The problem is that it never does overlap the specific image pixel position of the marker. I am using a AVCapturePreviewVideoLayer as to put the video in background that has the same bounds as my SceneKit View.

Has anyone has a clue why this happens? I tried to play with cameras FOV's but with no real impact in the results.

Thank you all for your time.

**EDIT1:** I Will post some of the code here to reveal what I am currently doing.

I have two subviews inside the main view, one which is a background AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and another which is a SceneKitView. Both have the same bounds as the main view.

At each frame I use an opencv wrapper which outputs the pose of each marker:

```
    std::vector<int> ids;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> corners, rejected;

    cv::aruco::detectMarkers(frame, _dictionary, corners, ids, _detectorParams, rejected);
    if (ids.size() > 0 ){
    cv::aruco::drawDetectedMarkers(frame, corners, ids);
    cv::Mat rvecs, tvecs;
    cv::aruco::estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, 2.6, _intrinsicMatrix, _distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);

    // Let's protect ourselves agains multiple markers
    if (rvecs.total() > 1)
        return;
    _markerFound = true;

    cv::Rodrigues(rvecs, _currentR);

    _currentT = tvecs;

    for (int row = 0; row < _currentR.rows; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < _currentR.cols; col++){
            _currentExtrinsics.at<double>(row, col) = _currentR.at<double>(row, col);
        }
        _currentExtrinsics.at<double>(row, 3) = _currentT.at<double>(row);
    }
    _currentExtrinsics.at<double>(3,3) = 1;
    std::cout << tvecs << std::endl;

    // Convert coordinate systems of opencv to openGL (SceneKit)
    // Note that in openCV z goes away the camera (in openGL goes into the camera)
    // and y points down and on openGL point up
    // Another note: openCV has a column order matrix representation, while SceneKit
    // has a row order matrix, but we'll take care of it later.
    cv::Mat cvToGl = cv::Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_64F);
    cvToGl.at<double>(0,0) = 1.0f;
    cvToGl.at<double>(1,1) = -1.0f; // invert the y axis
    cvToGl.at<double>(2,2) = -1.0f; // invert the z axis
    cvToGl.at<double>(3,3) = 1.0f;
    _currentExtrinsics = cvToGl * _currentExtrinsics;
    cv::aruco::drawAxis(frame, _intrinsicMatrix, _distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, 5);
```

Then in each frame I convert the opencv matrix for a SCN4Matrix:

```
- (SCNMatrix4) transformToSceneKit:(cv::Mat&) openCVTransformation{
SCNMatrix4 mat = SCNMatrix4Identity;
// Transpose
openCVTransformation = openCVTransformation.t();

// copy the rotationRows
mat.m11 = (float) openCVTransformation.at<double>(0, 0);
mat.m12 = (float) openCVTransformation.at<double>(0, 1);
mat.m13 = (float) openCVTransformation.at<double>(0, 2);
mat.m14 = (float) openCVTransformation.at<double>(0, 3);

mat.m21 = (float)openCVTransformation.at<double>(1, 0);
mat.m22 = (float)openCVTransformation.at<double>(1, 1);
mat.m23 = (float)openCVTransformation.at<double>(1, 2);
mat.m24 = (float)openCVTransformation.at<double>(1, 3);

mat.m31 = (float)openCVTransformation.at<double>(2, 0);
mat.m32 = (float)openCVTransformation.at<double>(2, 1);
mat.m33 = (float)openCVTransformation.at<double>(2, 2);
mat.m34 = (float)openCVTransformation.at<double>(2, 3);

//copy the translation row
mat.m41 = (float)openCVTransformation.at<double>(3, 0);
mat.m42 = (float)openCVTransformation.at<double>(3, 1)+2.5;
mat.m43 = (float)openCVTransformation.at<double>(3, 2);
mat.m44 = (float)openCVTransformation.at<double>(3, 3);

return mat;
```

}

At each frame in which the AR marker is found I add a box to the scene and apply the transformation to the object node:

```
SCNBox *box = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:5.0 height:5.0 length:5.0 chamferRadius:0.0];
_boxNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:box];
if (found){
    [self.delegate returnExtrinsicsMat:extrinsicMatrixOfTheMarker];
    Mat R, T;
    [self.delegate returnRotationMat:R];
    [self.delegate returnTranslationMat:T];
    SCNMatrix4 Transformation;
    Transformation = [self          transformToSceneKit:extrinsicMatrixOfTheMarker];
    //_cameraNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Invert(Transformation);
    [_sceneKitScene.rootNode addChildNode:_cameraNode];
    //_cameraNode.camera.projectionTransform = SCNMatrix4Identity;
    //_cameraNode.camera.zNear = 0.0;
    _sceneKitView.pointOfView = _cameraNode;
    _boxNode.transform = Transformation;


    [_sceneKitScene.rootNode addChildNode:_boxNode];
    //_boxNode.position = SCNVector3Make(Transformation.m41, Transformation.m42, Transformation.m43);

    std::cout << (_boxNode.position.x) << " " << (_boxNode.position.y) << " " << (_boxNode.position.z) << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

For example if the translation vector is (-1, 5, 20) the object appears in the scene in position (-1, -5, -20) in the scene, and the rotation is correct also. The problem is that it never appears in the correct position in the background image. I will add some images to show the result.

[image: Result1]

[image: Result2]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: How about posting some code and a screenshot? See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: You are using OpenCV to draw the coordinate system? If the transformation  of the box seems to be correct in SceneKit than there should be something wrong with your camera. Do you change the projection transform of the camera and is the transformation of the camera correct?

Comment: @orangenkopf Yes the axis is drawn with opencv. Currently I only apply the transform to the object node. The camera stays at (0,0,0) and I only change the object position/rotation. How can I set the correct projectionTransform of the camera node? I have the extrinsics of the camra, the intrinsics of the camera and the resultant transformation matrix. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Your [`SCNCamera`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scncamera?language=objc) has an [`projectionTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scncamera/1690501-projectiontransform?language=objc) property you can set.

Comment: I am aware of that, the problem is what to place in the projection matrix. I have tried different approaches but nothing seems to work well... @orangenkopf

Comment: Have you tried setting `xFov` and `yFov`? I am no expert on this, but in my AR project I am setting `(1.82147, 0, 0, 0,0, -2.42863, 0, 0,0, 0, 1.00501, 1,0, 0, -0.100251, 0)` as my `projectionTransform`. The results are fine but I have no idea where I found this value when I wrote it.

Comment: I tried different values of xFov and yFov. And from my research, projectionTransform should depend on the camera intrinsics fx, fy, cx and cy. Despite that I still haven't got it to work... Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the solution. Instead of applying the transform to the node of the object I applied the inverted transformation matrix to the camera node. Then for the camera perspective transform matrix I applied the following matrix:

```
    projection = SCNMatrix4Identity
    projection.m11 = (2 * (float)(cameraMatrix[0])) / -(ImageWidth*0.5)
    projection.m12 = (-2 * (float)(cameraMatrix[1])) / (ImageWidth*0.5)
    projection.m13 = (width - (2 * Float(cameraMatrix[2]))) / (ImageWidth*0.5)
    projection.m22 = (2 * (float)(cameraMatrix[4])) / (ImageHeight*0.5)
    projection.m23 = (-height + (2 * (float)(cameraMatrix[5]))) / (ImageHeight*0.5)
    projection.m33 = (-far - near) / (far - near)
    projection.m34 = (-2 * far * near) / (far - near)
    projection.m43 = -1
    projection.m44 = 0
```

being far and near the z clipping planes.

I also had to correct the box initial position to center it on the marker.

Comment: Would you be able to share the full source code for this?